# Google Cloud Billing --> Can I add a colleague who can add/admin a credit card?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, payment, billing, google-iam

I have my own Google Cloud account with my personal credit card associated with it (though I have some free credits right now).  I'm trying to add a colleague to my account who can associate a separate credit card to another project in my account.

Is this possible?  If so, what permissions are required?  I can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: A billing account has one primary credit card that processes all charges for all projects that the billing account is linked to. A project can have one billing account. If you want to use a different credit card for another project, you will need a different billing account. HYou can have multiple billing accounts. You can add multiple IAM member IDs to a billing account for management based upon billing roles. Edit your question to be clear on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **customer support** question. See: [Why customer support questions are off-topic here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) .

Comment: Thanks @John Conde, I should have checked that first!    And thanks John Hanley, I think that helps!